# In natural deduction, may a sequent we want to prove have another sequent as its premise?

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

For example can we have something like $(A\vdash B)\vdash C$ to prove in natural deduction? I've seen a single sequent this shape somewhere (don't remember where it was or if it was about natural deduction at all though!)

Comment: ;_; y u use symbol of metatheory on theory

Comment: @KennyLau lol X'D

Comment: @KennyLau look here https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_Absurdum/Sequent_Form it proves $(\neg p\vdash\bot)\vdash p$

Comment: Hmm, that isn't right

Comment: @KennyLau how about this one? https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Proof_by_Contradiction/Sequent_Form ($(p\vdash\bot)\vdash\neg p$) :D

Comment: I mean they shouldn't use it. I've left a message.

Comment: @KennyLau Hmmm not likely proofwiki would make such mistakes thou !

Comment: @Pooria The ProofWiki appears to be using $\vdash$ and the word "sequent" to describe informal, meta-theoretic implication. The only citation given on the https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_Absurdum/Sequent_Form page is to [Logic in Computer Science: Modelling and reasoning about systems](ftp://ftp.cs.bham.ac.uk/pub/authors/M.D.Ryan/tmp/Anongporn/Ch1+3.pdf). You can read the first three chapters at that link and verify that $(\neg p\vdash\bot)\vdash p$ never occurs and, in fact, no "nested" uses of $\vdash$ occur anywhere in the chapter in accordance to what Kenny Lau and I are saying.

Comment: It is an issue of symbolism... In natural deduction, we have to "write" dependency links between assumptiona and conclusion. In the book linked (like in many textbooks: van Dalen, Chiswell and Hodges) the rules are writed in 2D with dots; e.g. *DN* is ("linearizing" it) $\lnot p \ldots \bot / p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually not. $\vdash$ expects a list (or set) of (object-level) propositions and a proposition and $(A\vdash B)$ is not a(n object-level) proposition. That is, it's not a formula of the object language. This is almost always the case. There are systems of nested sequents ([e.g.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.1845)) that do allow things like this, but they are unusual.

Comment: I found that single sequent I mentioned: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_Absurdum/Sequent_Form that is $(\neg p\vdash\bot)\vdash p$

Comment: There's also this one: proofwiki.org/wiki/Proof_by_Contradiction/Sequent_Form $(p\vdash\bot)\vdash\neg p$